# ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 180, 180)

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Here is my code ,

I tried to build below CNN network , this error i am observing ,

```
model.add(Conv2D(8,3,activation='relu',padding='same',input_shape=(180,180)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(16,3,activation='relu',padding='same',input_shape=(180,180)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32,3,activation='relu',padding='same',input_shape=(180,180)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,3,activation='relu',padding='same',input_shape=(180,180)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128,3,activation='relu',padding='same',input_shape=(180,180)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(254, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax'))
```

The image_batch is a tensor of the shape (32, 180, 180, 3). This is a batch of 32 images of shape 180x180x3 (the last dimension refers to color channels RGB). The label_batch is a tensor of the shape (32,), these are corresponding labels to the 32 images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the CNN to process the inputs of shape

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(180, 180, 3)))
```

The first dimension is considered as the batch_size. If you specify `input_shape=(180,180)` then it means that `image_height=180, image_width=180` and the `batch_size=None` that means arbitrary number of samples could be given as input during model fit stage.